# C# Duplicates <k, v>

Tags: c#, generics, duplicates

I am new to learning C# and have a question.
I have a txt file with tests and scores like below

```
ACT
21.0
SAT
478.9
CLEP
69.1
ACT 32.0
```

How do I parse this txt to dictionary and display as below (removing any duplicates)

```
ACT 21.0
SAT 478.9
CLEP 69.1
```

Here is what I have attempted

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Generate
{
    class generateInputStream
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileManager objfileManager = new FileManager();
            FileStream fs = null;

            Console.Write("Enter the file path: ");

            while (fs == null)
            {
                string Path = Console.ReadLine();
                fs = objfileManager.OpenFile(Path);
            }
            int 

        }

    }

    public class FileManager
    {
        public FileStream OpenFile(string Path)
        {
            try
            {
                return new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write("Problem opening file {0}, please enter a valid path: ", Path);
            }
            return null;
        }

         public List<string> ReadLines(FileStream File)
        {
            List<string> text = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                var streamReader = new StreamReader(File);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.Message);
            }
            return text;
        }

        static readFileIntoDictionary()
        {
            StreamReader generateInputStream;
            var  streamReader  = new StreamReader();

            SortedDictionary<string, double> dic = new SortedDictionary<string, double>();

            string Key = string.Empty;
            double Value = 0.0;


            while ((Key = streamReader.ReadLine())!= null) 
            {
               Value = Convert.ToInt32(streamReader.ReadLine());

                dic.Add(Key, Value);   
            }
            streamReader.Close();

            return dic;
        }

        static displayScoreData()
        {
            readFileIntoDictionary(); 
           foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> pair in dic)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pair.Key, "-",pair.Value);
               }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to do your homework by yourself

Answer (score 0):

This method should help you a bit. There is no error handling here, so we assume your file is always in correct format.

```
public static KeyValuePair<string, decimal>? ReadPair (StreamReader sr)
{
    if (sr.EndOfStream) return null;

    string  key   = sr.ReadLine ();
    decimal value = decimal.Parse (sr.ReadLine ());

    return new KeyValuePair<string, decimal> (key, value);
}
```

I don't know what is a duplicate for you, the same key? The same key + value?